# Caching and Python Chunks

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a custom language chunk (the language mode is Python, but the execution engine sends the chunks to a Databricks cluster, see [1]).

when `cache=TRUE`, is the same logic for R code chunks relevant to other language code chunks or does the execution environment have to handle it itself? I ask because sometimes code is rerun despite my not having touched the code chunk.

Since these chunks are usually long running Spark jobs,honoring `cache=TRUE` is really important.

[1] https://github.com/saptarshiguha/rdatabricks/blob/master/R/knitr_engines.R#L3